# we can sent the mail in wordpress "your host may have disabled" text only show

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to send mail in `wordpress`. getting the below error.

> The e-mail could not be sent. Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.

Comment: You need ask the question to hosting provider, sorry for my English

Comment: Highlighted your error message. please share your code snippet. Use wp_mail - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail